# Hibernate Search Fails with Double Type Greater than 5 Digits

Tags: hibernate, lucene, double, hibernate-search

I have the following fields on an entity:

```
@Field(index = Index.TOKENIZED, store = Store.YES)
@Column(name = "total_credit_amount", nullable = false)
@FieldBridge(impl = RoundedDoubleBridge.class)
private Double totalCreditAmount;

@Field(index = Index.TOKENIZED, store = Store.YES)
@Column(name = "total_debit_amount", nullable = false)
@FieldBridge(impl = RoundedDoubleBridge.class)
private Double totalDebitAmount;
```

The Double to String bridge implementation is the following:

```
public class RoundedDoubleBridge
    implements StringBridge
{
@Override
    public String objectToString(Object value)
    {
        // Do not index null strings
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (value instanceof Double)
        {
            long price = round((Double) value);

            return Long.toString(price);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                RoundedDoubleBridge.class + " used on a non double type: "
                + value.getClass());
        }
    }


    private long round(double price)
    {
        double rounded = Math.floor(price / 3) * 3;

        if (rounded != price)
        {
            rounded += 3; //we round up
        }

        return (long) rounded;
    }
}
```

So the issue here is that the search I am performing retreives results whenever the values on totalDebitAmount or totalCreditAmount are less than 100000, whenever they are greater or equal to 100000 search fails.. Any help appreciated..

The following is the way I am making the search:

```
public List<AbstractRecord> doSearch(String stringToFind)
    {
        List<AbstractRecord> result = null;

        // Test Search for specific values of an Abstract Record
        // Aim to return the number of retreived results
        em = emf.createEntityManager();

        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
            org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);

        //em.getTransaction().begin();
        String[] fields = // Fields to be reviewed
            new String[]
            {
               ....,
               "totalCreditAmount", "totalDebitAmount",
               ....
            };

        //Create a multi-field Lucene query
        StandardAnalyzer stdAnalyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);
        MultiFieldQueryParser parser =
            new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, fields, stdAnalyzer);
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = null;

        try
        {
            query = parser.parse(stringToFind);
        }
        catch (ParseException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(SearchFacade.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Wrap Lucene query in a javax.persistence.Query
        javax.persistence.Query persistenceQuery =
            fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query);
        // Execute search
        result = (List<AbstractRecord>) persistenceQuery.getResultList();
        em.close();

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: fails as in returns zero results? throws an error?

Comment: Hi,returns zero results. I think it is related with the Analyzer, not sure though, I am a Hibernate Search & Lucene Query Newb. If anyone can light me up, I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Edit: Testing with an Integer value of 6 or more digits the search succeds... So I guess my bridge Implementation is the cause of the search failure?? Thanks

Comment: Edit: Hypotheses from my colleagues suggest that scientific notation applied to the double type is the one causing this problem... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I feel kind of dumb.
I found my problem..
It is specifically at the rounding function of the implementation of my *FieldBridge*
The relevant snippet of the bridge is the following:

```
private long round(double price)
    {
        double rounded = Math.floor(price / 3) * 3;

        if (rounded != price)
        {
            rounded += 3; //we round up
        }

        return (long) rounded;
    }
```

Notice for price = 100000 the variable *rounded* = 99999
After checking the if condition since its different from price, it will add 3, hence indexing 100002 instead of 100000, therefore If I look up for 100002 I will find the appropriate record..

Lessons learned here:

- If you are implementing a customized
  *DoubleBridge* that pads and/or rounds
  make sure the rounding function meets
  all your data value ranges to avoid
  problems like the one I had..
- If you need to show in screen rounded
  up Doubles in plain notation and not
  scientific, you will need to implement
  a *TwoWayStringBridge* that performs
  the *ObjectToString* conversion padding
  and rounding and later on the
  *StringToObject* conversion returning a
  plain notation Double and not on its
  scientific notation.

Hope this post can help anyone with similar issues. Greets